# Embedding a .swf file generated by Adobe Encore with external videos into an Adobe AIR app with Flash Pro

Tags: air, flash, embed, loader

everyone. I hope someone can help me with this. I am doing an AIR application project and need to embed a swf file generated by Encore which in turn embeds a video (F4V) file. I get the following errors when loading it with a Loader object:

```
 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.managers::FocusManager/activate()
    at spark.components::Application/initManagers()
    at spark.components::Application/initialize()
    at EncoreSWF/initialize()
    at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/childAdded()
    at mx.managers.systemClasses::ChildManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/initializeTopLevelWindow()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I know Flash Professional quite well, but Flash Builder not at all. The following is my code:

```
    import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var showBusinessPlay:Loader = new Loader;
showBusinessPlay.x = 0;
showBusinessPlay.y = 0;
showBusinessPlay.width = 1024;
showBusinessPlay.height = 768;
showBusinessPlay.visible = true;
showBusinessPlay.load(new URLRequest("TestFlash/flashdvd.swf"));
showBusinessPlay.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,addToStage);
function addToStage(event:Event):void{
    stage.addChild(showBusinessPlay);
}
```

If there is any way to do this, which I know there will be, please help me. If it needs to be done with Flash Builder and swc files, please tell me what steps I must follow to do this.

Darius

Answer (score 0):

I dont´t think this has anything to do with the SWF. Could you show us a little bit more of the code?

And this line is not correct:

```
var showBusinessPlay:Loader = new Loader;
```

it needs to be

```
var showBusinessPlay:Loader = new Loader();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, codingbuddha. I unfortunately deleted that files and decided to go the old-fashioned way of coding all the video controls myself, but I would like to go do it with encore still. There wasn't a lot more code, but could you maybe tell me what do you think it might be?